# bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't use available space and breaks on pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

My dropdown looks like this:

```
<a uib-dropdown-toggle class="tm-notification" href="">
    <i class="tmn-counts" id="idItemNumber">666</i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-right dropdown-menu-lg">
    <div class="listview">
        <div class="lv-header">
            A title here
        </div>
        <div class="lv-body c-overflow">
            <div class="lv-item">
                <div class="lv-title">
                    <div class="pull-left">Some very long text here</div>
                    <div class="pull-right">01-06-2016</div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which results in the `pull-right` div breaking to the next line.

[image]

I'm not sure how many of those css classes are standard bootstrap, but the `dropdown-menu` div's css has:

```
min-width: 300px;
```

If I add `width: 345px;` the result is correct but it's not dynamic anymore.
So I want dropdown-menu's width to depend on its content.

I tried to have all the data in 1 pull-left div

```
<div class="pull-left">Some very very long text here 01-01-2016</div>
```

The width reacts normally but then I don't have the date pulled right.

Comment: I had to wrap the pull-right and pull-left in a div class row. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a uib-dropdown-toggle class="tm-notification" href="">
    <i class="tmn-counts" id="idItemNumber">666</i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu pull-right dropdown-menu-lg">
    <div class="listview">
        <div class="lv-header">
            A title here
        </div>
        <div class="lv-body c-overflow">
            <div class="lv-item">
                <div class="lv-title">
                    <div class="pull-left col-sm-7">Some very long text here</div>
                    <div class="pull-right col-sm-5">01-06-2016</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with this, text and date are overlapping

Comment: open jsfiddle please

Comment: I had to wrap the pull-right and pull-left in a div class row. Now it works. You helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple use label for date and give pull-right class for it.

```
<div class="lv-body c-overflow">
            <div class="lv-item">
                <div class="lv-title">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">Some very long text here <label class="pull-right">01- 06-2016</label></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: this doesn't do much but bolding the date.

Comment: I had to wrap the pull-right and pull-left in a div class row. Now it works.